# JDBI Transaction when using dao to another class

Tags: java, transactions, jdbi

Here is what I have:

**UserDao**

```
public interface UserDao {
    @SqlUpdate("...")
    int action1(@BindBean(..))

    @SqlUpdate("...")
    int action2(@BindBean(..))
}
```

**UserManager**

```
public class UserManager {
    private final UserDao dao;

    public UserManager (final UserDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
        // there are other daos and clients passed here
    }

    @Transaction
    public void foo() {
        action1();
        action2();
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
public class UserRepository {
    private final UserManager manager;

    public UserRepository(final UserManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        manager.foo();
    }
}
```

This `@Transaction` doesn't do anything; how can I add transaction support for the structure that I have here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do what you want is:

1. You must have access to DBI instance from transactional method body. Either pass it as method parameter or have as service instance field.
2. Inside transactional method call dbi.inTransaction(...) (or dbi.useTransaction(...) if you don't need to return a result) passing in a callback. You don't need @Transactional annotation on this method anymore.
3. In callback, obtain instance of every dao you need with handle.attach(YourDaoInterface.class)

That's it.

UPD.
So, your code will look like (assuming you use Java8 or newer):

```
public class UserManager {

private final DBI dbi;

public UserManager (final DBI dbi) {
    this.dbi = dbi;
    // there are other daos and clients passed here
}

public void foo() {
    dbi.useTransaction((handle, transactionStatus) -> {
        UserDao dao = handle.attach(UserDao.class);
        dao.action1();
        dao.action2();
    });
  }
}
```

Here's JUnit+Mockito code used to write unit tests for such service methods:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
........

@Mock
private Handle handle;

@Mock
private UserDao userDao;

@Spy
private DBI dbi = new DBI(mock(ConnectionFactory.class));

@InjectMocks
private UserManager userManager;

@Before
public void setUpDbi() {
    Mockito.doReturn(handle)
            .when(dbi).open();
    Mockito.when(handle.attach(UserDao.class))
            .thenReturn(userDao);

    TransactionStatus status = Mockito.mock(TransactionStatus.class);

    Answer<Object> transactionalAnswer = invocation ->
            ((TransactionCallback) invocation.getArguments()[0])
                    .inTransaction(handle, status);

    Mockito.when(handle.inTransaction(any()))
            .thenAnswer(transactionalAnswer);
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to give a mock example with using the `useTransaction` method? I can't seem to be able to successfully mock this call.

Comment: I am also looking for the same, and reached here :)

Comment: @Amaravathi Use `doAnswer`